# SPEAK: Not able to add items to ComboBox

Tags: speak

I am new to SPEAK and trying to implement a module. I have a combo-box which will list item names. I am trying to add items to combo-box through JavaScript but items are not getting added. Below is my code

```
define(["sitecore"], function (Sitecore) {
var model = Sitecore.Definitions.Models.ControlModel.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this._super();
        app = this;
        this.set("itemlist", "");
        this.on("change:itemlist", this.FillItems, this);
    },
    FillItems:function(){
         var tmpData = '{ "items" : [' +
        '{ "itemId":"{E932156B-3269-44AB-ADB2-60E50C56730A}" , "itemName":"My item 1" },' +
        '{ "itemId":"{DB534C88-F1D2-4BC5-B5A6-AF341E331432}" , "itemName":"My item 2" }]}';
        var obj = JSON.parse(tmpData);
        this.viewModel.app.ComboBox1.viewModel.rebind(obj,null,null,"itemName","itemId");
    }
});

var view = Sitecore.Definitions.Views.ControlView.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this._super();
    }
});

Sitecore.Factories.createComponent("ItemsList", model, view, ".sc-ItemsList");});
```

Can anyone tell what I have done wrong in this code?.

Comment: Can you use the following `this.viewModel.app.ComboBox1.DynamicData = obj;` instead of `this.viewModel.app.ComboBox1.viewModel.rebind(obj,null,null,"itemName","itemId");`

Comment: @HishaamNamooya. I tried, but still items are not getting added to the ComboBox.

Comment: Can you just call the FillItems function instead from the on change event for testing. Because from the code you shared, it seems that the drop down will get populated when the change event is triggered

Comment: FillItems function getting called with my above code itself. I have tried to call the function without change event also. But both are not filling the comboBox.

Answer (score 1):

As I was looking a way to achieve this, I found this post and as a basis to get started. Using the `rebind` method, a simple array is sufficient to be used for `obj`.

```
var obj = [
{ "itemId":"{E932156B-3269-44AB-ADB2-60E50C56730A}" , "itemName":"My item 1" },
{ "itemId":"{DB534C88-F1D2-4BC5-B5A6-AF341E331432}" , "itemName":"My item 2" }
];
this.viewModel.app.ComboBox1.viewModel.rebind(obj,null,null,‌​"itemName","itemId")‌​;
```